# switch in xaml to register different controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, enums

Im not sure if this is possible so I do not have a code example for you. basically I am looking to see if I can switch in xaml to insert a specific control based on enum value. sodo code below should give you an example of what I am looking for

```
enum testVariable{ btn = 2, input = 2 }
```

xaml

```
xaml switch binding to testvariable
         if testvariable = 1
 <button/>
         if testvaribale = 2
 <textbox/>
```

basically I am looking to build a dynamic form input based on enum variable in a list as part of a structure.

Comment: Is this for items in a items control e.g. ListBox?

Comment: You question is not much clear, can you please put xaml or explian it more. like you want to display single content or item inside the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom DataTemplateSelector, which will choose a data template based on your enum value.

```
public class EnumDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ButtonDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate InputDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, 
               DependencyObject container)
    {
        var value = (testVariable)item;

        switch (value)
        {
            case testVariable.btn:
                return ButtonDataTemplate;
            case testVariable.input:
                return InputDataTemplate;
        }

        return InputDataTemplate;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DataTemplates.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:DataTemplates"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <Window.Resources>

        <!-- DataTemplate for Button -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate">
           <Button/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- DataTemplate for Input -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="InputDataTemplate">
           <TextBox/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- DataTemplate Selector -->
        <l:PropertyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"
              ButtonDataTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonDataTemplate}"
              InputDataTemplate="{StaticResource InputDataTemplate}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!--List box-->
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                 ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}"/>
        <!--Content control-->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                 ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

if you create your own you can pass in any data, perform your selection based on that and then return the correct template on your selection

eg

code

```
public class CustomTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    DataTemplate Template1{get;set};
    DataTemplate Template2{get;set};
    DataTemplate Template3{get;set};
    DataTemplate Template4{get;set};

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var data = item as YourDataType
        switch(data.Enum)
        {
           case Enum.Value1:
                return Template1;
           case Enum.Value2:
                return Template2;
           case Enum.Value3:
                return Template3;
           case Enum.Value4:
                return Template4;
           default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<local:CustomeDataTemplate>
    <local:CustomeDataTemplate.Template1>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox />
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:CustomeDataTemplate.Template1>
    <local:CustomeDataTemplate.Template2>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:CustomeDataTemplate.Template2>
</local:CustomeDataTemplate>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12015209)

Comment: unfortunately the essential part is that they need to understand how to use a template selector which required reading a majority of the page, and as its a MSDN link its unlikely to be orphaned, however i've had time to write the example i was intending to add to it